# Where can I find an English or Bengali book on Havan/Yajna/Homa?

Tags: yajna, resource, homam

I am looking for a book on "how to perform Havan (Hawan/Yajna/Hom)" in English or Bengali. But, unfortunately, I could not find it. There are many books in Hindi. But I can't read Hindi. So, if anybody knows any book, please provide the link. Even if the book is not free, it is okay.

Comment: For Tantrika homa (https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.338822). For Vaidik homa (https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.358085/page/n5/mode/1up). Besides, every puja paddhati book does contain homavidhi.

Comment: Shri PVR Narasimha Rao ji has prepared excellent manuals to perform homas for free for everyone, you can check them out on his website vedicastrologer.com !

Comment: @Rāmachandra thank you so much. Really useful resource.